# Mariadb Engine-Independent Table Statistics migration upgrade 10.3 to 10.5

Tags: mariadb, innodb, mariadb-10.5

We upgrade MariaDB version from 10.3 to 10.5. Some explain plans change for worst plans.
We see that documentation https://mariadb.com/kb/en/engine-independent-table-statistics/ and we see that

> use_stat_tables='preferably_for_queries'

is default configuration but we have **empty** tables for engine independent stats so I expected that it use innodb stats but if change it to *never* or *complementary_for_queries* I get another (usually better) execution plan. So I was very surprised of that.

Next if I want use engine independent stats I need to process some (or all) tables stats with `ANALYZE TABLE tbl PERSISTENT FOR ALL;`
But it's freeze database, so I understand that I can use a slave generate and copy them (not very friendly with varbinary and blob columns).

And finally I don't know how explain plan will become.
I fact I did it and that's not give me better explain plan (same plan with empty stats tables) with *use_stat_tables='preferably_for_queries'* option and I did `flush table`.

So I'm block with *use_stat_tables='never'* so do I need user independent engine stats ? How to do that ?

Update:
With engine independent stats tables empty why a get different explain plans when a switch from *use_stat_tables='never'* to *use_stat_tables='preferably_for_queries'* ? Is it a bug ?

Comment: Show us a query that got worse.  We may be able to provide an improvement that will be faster in both versions.

Comment: My question is not an optimisation issue, but a how to use stats engine independent feature without what'll happen to queries plans.

Comment: Consider filing a bug at jira,mariadb.org